# Perl: Log every execution of all scripts

Tags: logging, perl

Is there a way to log every execution of perl scripts on the complete server?
I am investigating a possible security issue and therefore want to log every perl execution.

Is something like this possible?

Thanks in advance

PS: Running CentOS 6.5 including Plesk 12

Comment: The only way I could think of it is using a wrapper, but unfortunately that causes a whole new set of issues.  This issue comes up for different reasons, moreso because people want to use a wrapper to use different versions of perl on the same machine.  You can look up "perl wrapper" and see the types of headaches involed.  Sorry :(  Hopefully the wrapper idea gives you some other ideas though.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is auditing. Logging 'every time perl is run' isn't particularly easy - as the other poster mentions, wrappers can be a real pain to manage, and doesn't stop someone having their own perl binary.

However, CentOs does support Kernel Auditing. In which a record is made of *lots* of things, and people don't usually bother because it's extremely verbose.

I'm afraid I can't give any more detail really, because auditing tends to be a real pain to set up and enable first time, but otherwise you don't really need to touch it. I would suggest you look in your favourite search engine for how to enable and configure.

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/chap-system_auditing.html should help you get auditing going